# Problem with reassigning spinner value

Tags: android, android-widget

I trying to get a value off a spinner and then pass it onto another java file.  I have a spinner in which has a number of values.  I change this value, convert it to a string, then on the click of a button I use and intent to pass this information onto the other java file to do stuff with.

The problem I am having is that once I initially set the spinner value even though I change the spinner the value that is passed on is not changed.

Even if I change the spinner the position value that is passed on to LiquidFlowResults is still possize = 0 as originally assigned.

```
/** initially setting spinner value */
int possize = 0;
String pipeSizeString = Integer.toString(possize);

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button calculateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    calculateButton.setOnClickListener(mEnableListener);


    Spinner spinnerPipeSize = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerPipeSize);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterpipesize = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.pipesize_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapterpipesize.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerPipeSize.setAdapter(adapterpipesize);    

    spinnerPipeSize.setOnItemSelectedListener(new PipeSizeOnItemSelectedListener());

/** Listening for spinner position */

public class PipeSizeOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
        View view, int possize, long id) {
        String pipeSizeString = Integer.toString(possize);
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
      // Do nothing.
    }
}

/** passing on information on click of button */

private OnClickListener mEnableListener = new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(LiquidFlow.this, LiquidFlowResults.class);
        Bundle sizeposition = new Bundle();
                sizeposition.putString("pipeSizeStringPositionMoved", pipeSizeString);
                intent.putExtras(sizeposition);
    startActivity(intent);

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for PipeSizeOnItemSelectedListener. You can just call getSelectedItemPosition in OnClickListener.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, but when I add the line:  int possize = spinnerPipeSize.getSelectedItemPosition(); to OnClickListener Eclipse tells me that spinnerPipeSize cannot be resolved.  I thought I had defined it enough in the onCreate

Comment: Found the answer, you put me on the correct path but I had to use getLastVisiblePosition instead of getSelectedItemPosition as I was looking to return a int to work with on Click.  Code that worked in my onClick statement was:       Spinner spinnerPipeSize = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerPipeSize);
      int possize = spinnerPipeSize.getLastVisiblePosition();
      String pipeSizeString = Integer.toString(possize);